# How can i get and use the comment produced by an indicator that is in ex4 format?

Tags: mql4

i have a zigzag indicator that comment buy or sell on Forex main chart. i want to use the comment to carry out trade activities. Thank you

Comment: @Martijn Pieters, any reason to delete my answer? another question was answered by mistake with this answer, and replaced. I believe the answer given was correct

Comment: `string comment=ChartGetString(0,CHART_COMMENT);`
`0` here is id of the chart (`0` for current).